# What are the recommended proguard settings for android support library?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am using android-support-library-v7 in my project and of course I would like to use progurad to minimize and obfuscate my code.
The problem is that if I use proguard I get errors similar to this:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.example.project/org.example.project.ActivityMain}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory
    at android.support.v7.preference.g.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.preference.g.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.preference.g.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.preference.g.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.preference.g.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.preference.h.a(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.preference.h.b(Unknown Source)
    at org.exampple.project.ActivityMain.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
    ... 11 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:431)
    ... 22 more
```

PreferenceCategory is used in my preferences.xml file and I guess it is accessed via reflection. Proguard if probably removes this method (or class) if it is not referenced in code when shrinking. And even if not it surely obfuscates the name.
Google in itßs usual fashion provides absolutely no documentation on the subject.

So, what are the optimum settings to achieve good shrinking and good obfuscation.
There are some similar questions on Stack Overflow, but they boil down to:

```
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
```

which cleary defeats the purpose of shrinking and obfuscating.

Trying to randomly guess the settings or by try and error method is extremely time consuming.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Support Library uses the [`consumerProguardFiles`](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType:consumerProguardFiles) feature to automatically include the appropriate ProGuard if you're using Gradle, meaning you don't need to manually include anything.

Looking at the ProGuard file for `preferences-v7` (stored in the proguard.txt file within the AAR), it contains the following lines:

```
# Preference objects are inflated via reflection
-keep public class android.support.v7.preference.Preference {
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}
-keep public class * extends android.support.v7.preference.Preference {
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}
```

Which covers the exact method that it says you are missing (as `PreferenceCategory` indirectly extends `Preference`). Check to make sure you are using the full Gradle dependency.

Comment: Thank you. I am not using gradle. Therefore not so easy for me. Upvoted.

Comment: @user6694745 - then you'll need to make sure you manually extract the rules from every proguard.txt file in every AAR you are pulling in every time you upgrade the Support Library. It is strongly recommended to use Gradle.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [project](https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/tree/master/libraries) on Github that has `proguard` rules for popular libraries.

Comment: I have seen that. Those few examples about support library stick to keep everything pattern. And, they miss other stuff like Preferences. Therefore incomplete and less than optimal.